# Basic Topology, curved square

Tags: topology, bevel

Relatively new to blender, but at the minute I am trying to get my head around good modelling and topology. I'm using some basic models as a reference and then trying to recreate lighting, materials, and modelling. I have attached a reference for what I'm trying to recreate, but struggling to create the square without getting artifacts that are effecting shading and the basic shape. Included is an image of where I have the topology now, and also an image of what seems like it would work best for adding a bevel to edges

Any help or advice for how to get the modelling correct is appreciated[image: Model]

[image: my topology]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

what about this:

1. create a cube and <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to resize

[image]

2. select these edges (edge selection):

[image]

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and mouse wheel up

[image]

then add *Bevel Modifier* + shade autosmooth

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, no need for quads :). I'd perhaps check Harden normals, but that's just nitpicking :))

Comment: I would add a single inset faces to that quad, after which the ngon will be perfectly planar with its neighbors, preventing any smooth shading or c-c subdivision artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your supportive comments!

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I think I'm missing a step somewhere to get to the last images topology, I have followed all the above steps, not working, then I have tried to apply the bevel modifier or go into edit mode and ctrl+b the edges, auto shade seems to do nothing, its obviously something simple but I am definitely missing something here, thanks in advance, I was so full of hope when I saw the replies but stuck again

Comment: ok, pls make a video of what you did so we can see what you did and correct you. Or really describe step by step what keys your are typing and what menus your are chose.

Comment: @StephenKenny hi the link you added in your edit suggestion does not work. perhaps because you need to be logged in so i removed it.

Comment: Apologies for delayed response, super busy with work, I can't seem to upload my video, but the steps I have taken are 

1. Resize cube, S+Z
2. Edit mode, select each corner edge as displayed above
3. Ctrl+B to bevel width .2m and 5 segments
4. Shade smooth, Object data panel, normals, shade smooth at 30 degrees
5. Object mode, add bevel modifier (amount 0.024) (segments 5) (angle 30degrees)

I feel there is a step missing after this?